# Using next_permutation to get palindrome string

Tags: c++, permutation

I'm trying to make a program that tries every permutation in the string to check if it can create palindrome string or not. If not it deletes one char and tries again and so on till you find a solution. I can't figure why it gives me a segmentation fault. Here is my code:

```
bool IsPalindrome(string s){
string t;
int x=s.size()-1;
for(int i=x;i>=0;i--)
    t+=s[i];

 if(s==t)
     return true;
 else
     return false;
}

void generate_permutation(string s,int i){
 sort(s.begin(),s.end());
do{
if(IsPalindrome(s)){
    if(i%2==0){
        cout<<"First"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Second"<<endl;
        exit(0);
       }
   }

}while(next_permutation(s.begin(),s.end())) ;


 }


int main(){


string s;
cin>>s;
int i=0;
while(s.size()>=1){
generate_permutation(s,i);
s.erase(s.begin()+i);
i++;
   }



}
```

Comment: And what is your question

Comment: You don't need to try all permutations; just ensure you have an even count for each unique character (and optionally one unique character with an odd count).

Comment: `if (foo) return true; else return false;` is redundant and is equivalent to `return foo;` in a Boolean context.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
while(s.size()>=1){ // size() goes down to 1
generate_permutation(s,i);
s.erase(s.begin()+i); // the i'th element is always the one erased
i++; // i goes up and up
```

Perhaps you intend to remove the first or last character, instead of the first, then the second, then the third…

Comment: yesh solved this problem and comments was very useful thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you want

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    for (cin >> s; s.size(); ) {
        sort(s.begin(), s.end());
        do {
            if (equal(s.begin(), s.end(), s.rbegin())) {    // Palindrome check
                cout << s << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        } while (next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));    // all permutations
        string::iterator it = unique(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char a, char b) {
                return a != b;
            });    // first non repeating char
        s.erase(it != s.end() ? it : s.begin());    // erase a char
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Input**

```
abaca
```

**Sample Output**

```
aaa
```

See demo http://ideone.com/VgTEgS.